# Power bi slicer not active, then no selection

Tags: powerbi

I do habe a slicer which filters a simple table. The slicer works perfectly fine, but obviously if the slicer is not active, all rows in the table are shown. Is there a option where the table is going to be empty when nothing is selected in the slicer? I know I can add another option to the slicer which empties the table, but I am looking more for a "default option".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a measure which only returns a value if the slicer field is filtered:

```
Filtered MyMeasure = 
    IF ( 
        CALCULATE ( 
            ISFILTERED ( 'Dimension Table'[Sliced Field] ),
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Dimension Table'[Sliced Field] )
        ),
        [MyMeasure],
        BLANK()
    )
```